# How to optimize withColumn in Spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new at Spark and Scala and I want to optimize a request that I wrote on Spark which is very very heavy and slow (my database is huge and it contains a lot of data).

I have a first table "city_ID" :

```
ID      City_CODE
1          10
2          11
3          12
```

And a second table "city_name" that has a common field with the first one :

```
City_Code  City_NAME_CRYPT
10          ADFKJV - Paris
11          AGHDFBNLKFJ - London
12          AGZEORIUYG- Madrid
```

What I want to have in my final result is the city id and its proper name (which I can compute with a regex on the city_name field) WITHOUT ANY OTHER DATA. So, it should look like this :

```
ID          NAME
10          Paris
11          London
12          Madrid
```

Here is my current code :

```
val result = spark.sql(""" SELECT t1.id, t2.city_name_crypt AS name_crypt
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2
on t1.city_code = t2.city_code""").withColumn("name", regexp_extract($"name_crypt", ".*?(\\d+)\\)$", 1)).drop($"name_crypt").show()
```

The big problem for me is that I just want to have 2 columns, not 3! But since I did an inner join I am obliged to keep this third column on my dataframe while it's useless in my case. It's why I used the drop after the with column method.

Can you please help me to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think that's not what is making it slow.  But you can use withColumnRenamed like so...

`result.withColumnRenamed("name", regexp_extract($"name_crypt", ".*?(\\d+)\\)$", 1))`

If you are new to Spark a lot of people don't parallelize the tasks at first. Perhaps you should make sure that the parallelization of your tasks is good. Check the `num-executors` and `executor-memory`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Here is an example spark-submit command...

```
spark-submit \

  --class yourClass \

  --master yarn \

  --deploy-mode cluster \  

  --executor-memory 8G \

  --num-executors 40 \

  /path/to/myJar.jar
```

Comment: Code you have is right, you can't do much about it. If your application is running slow either you have to vertically scale if you have less resource on node or increase your worker nodes.